Appsync + Apollo GQL
Looking for few pointers for a challenge I am struggling with at the moment.
So basically I have a Strapi CMS that has a gql api, then I have appsync as the endpoint that front ends talks to. Appsync Schema needs to expose the Strapi api ideally with the same schema but would have more additional data sources and fields from lambdas and dynamodb. Also I need have a 2-3hr cache layer between appsync and Strapi to avoid overloading the cms. Any pointers would be much appreciated.
Cheers
I have tried $ctx.info.getSelectionSetGraphQL approach a bit but it seems to drop query parameters and I can’t see how I go about integrating other data sources
